# Telerik MVC3 grid with custom Edit/Insert popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, grid, telerik, popup

I'm new to MVC, and I was trying to create a page to list items, and I can Add/Edit items in this list.

I used telerik MVC grid to show the list of items, what I want now is to know is there a way to customize how the add/edit popup of the telerik grid.

The reason is that I need to hide some fields, and add some other lookups.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a [detailed](http://markfreedman.com/index.php/2011/08/09/wrestling-with-the-telerik-mvc-grid-control-part-1/) [series](http://markfreedman.com/index.php/2011/11/13/wrestling-with-the-telerik-mvc-grid-control-part-2/) on a master/detail AJAX-driven Telerik MVC grid, which makes use of an editor template in the detail grid's editor pop-up, and also hides some columns (getting around some issues with that). I discuss this in [part 3](http://markfreedman.com/index.php/2012/02/08/wrestling-with-the-telerik-mvc-grid-control-part-3/), and you can download the full sample app. Hopefully that can help a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom Editor Template. In the folder EditorTemplates under Views/Shared, add a view that has the **name of your model**. When you use pop up editing, it will use the template you defined.

Telerik has an example project demonstrating how this is done: [Custom PopUp Editor Form](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/grid/custom-popup-editor-form.aspx).

Here is the code for an Editor Template I made for a project where my model was Tasks:

```
@model Whiteboard.Models.Tasks

<fieldset>
    <legend>Tasks</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.TID)

    <div>
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(w => w.Task):<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Task, new { style = "width: 375px;" })
    </p>
    </div>
    <div>
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(w => w.WDate):<br />
        @Html.EditorFor(c => c.WDate)
    </p>
    </div>
    <div>
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(w => w.Description):<br />
        @Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.Description, new { cols = "45", rows = "15", @class = "ext_TextArea" })
    </p>
    </div>
    <div>
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(w => w.Notes):<br />
        @Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.Notes, new { cols = "45", rows = "5", @class = "ext_TextArea" })
    </p>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: it works , but when I tried to save the data it did not work and I can see this error in firebug "a(this).data("tTextBox") is undefined "; am I missing something?

Comment: My guess is there is a problem with the mapping between the textbox and your model. Make sure you have the correct field name in the editor template. Beyond that, I'm not sure.

Comment: what I'm sure of is that is something related to telerik scripts, and that I do not have any field with that name "tTextBox"

Comment: also I noticed that when I added a datepicker I can't open the selection window!!