# Adding a button in a Telerik RadGrid editor column

Tags: asp.net, telerik, imagebutton, radgrid

I have this Telerik radgrid

```
| Encryption Key | Password to encode | Edit column |
-----------------------------------------------------
|    A_Key       | A_password         | Edit button |
```

When I press the edit button, you can edit the encryption key and the password via textboxes (which works fine).

What I want to do is:

-When I press the edit button, I want to add an imagebutton next to the encryption key textbox that will allow me to generate a key by clicking it, like so:

```
| Encryption Key        | Password to encode | Edit column |
------------------------------------------------------------
|[A_Key     ][Generate] | [A_password      ] | [Save]      |
```

**Is there a way to add a button inside an editor cell of a Telerik RadGrid?**

I have looked everywhere, I haven't found any way to do this, even on the Telerik website/forums.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this asp.net mvc? If so, this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216168/telerik-mvc3-grid-with-custom-edit-insert-popup/9217374#9217374.

Comment: No, I'm not using MVC. I'd prefer having the edit fields in the radgrid itself, not in a popup div. The editorTemplate will be my last resort tho, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have used a solution similar to Dhaval's. Using server side controls wasn't optimal for me, so I used jquery to generate keys client side.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="Generate" DataField="" HeaderText=""  AllowFiltering="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <img id="Generate" src="Images/generate.gif" onclick="javascript: GenerateEncryptionKey();" alt="Generate key" title="Generate key"/>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

What this will do is it will create a column for the button only. Using CSS, I can make it look like a single column.

```
| Encryption Key |            | Password to encode | Edit column |
------------------------------------------------------------
|[A_Key         ]| [Generate] | [A_password      ] | [Save]      |
```

I'm not displaying column lines, so it looks like 1 large column rather than 2 small columns.

Thanks to all for your answers!

Answer (score 3):

```
 <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" UniqueName="Status">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("Status") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBx" />
                <asp:Button id="btn" OnClick="btn_Click" runat="server" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

And create a onclick event function on back end like this:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Your Code Goes here
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's not exactly what I'm looking for, but I figured it out thanks to you.