# Cannot display Raw Html in Telerik Grid's Popup Editor using an ASCX template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I looked at [Telerik MVC3 grid with custom Edit/Insert popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216168/telerik-mvc3-grid-with-custom-edit-insert-popup) and it was almost there.  However, I am trying to figure out how to display some HTML Text that is generated by the Controller for each row in the Grid - but in the Popup-Editor!  (I can easily display it in a grid column simply by adding **.Encoded(false)** to my column definition.)

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Grid<ViewModelProcurementAction>(Model.ProcurementActions) // 
        .Name("ProcurementActionGrid")
        .Columns(c =>
            {
                c.Command(commands =>
                    {
                        commands.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.ImageAndText);
                        commands.Delete().ButtonType(GridButtonType.ImageAndText);
                        commands.Custom("showHistory")
                                .ButtonType(GridButtonType.ImageAndText)
                                .Text("History")
                                .Action("Show", "ProcurementActions")
                                .DataRouteValues(route => { route.Add(o => o.Id).RouteKey("id"); });
                    }).Title("Actions").Width(100);
                c.Bound(e => e.Id).Visible(false);
                c.Bound(e => e.ActionId).Visible(false);
                c.Bound(e => e.ContractNumber).HtmlAttributes(new {style = "vertical-align: top"});
                c.Bound(e => e.ContractManager).Width(120).HtmlAttributes(new {style = "vertical-align: top"});
                c.Bound(e => e.ActualCAResponsible).Width(150).HtmlAttributes(new {style = "vertical-align: top"});
                c.Bound(e => e.TitleOfRequirement).HtmlAttributes(new {style = "vertical-align: top"});
                c.Bound(e => e.CipOrName).Title("Project Id").HtmlAttributes(new {style = "vertical-align: top"});
                c.Bound(e => e.RecordTypeName).Title("Record Type").HtmlAttributes(new {style = "vertical-align: top"});
                c.Bound(e => e.ContractTypeName).Title("Contract Type").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "vertical-align: top" });
                c.Bound(e => e.ProcurementActionYearDisplayName).Title("Plan FY").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "vertical-align: top" });
            })
        .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(o => o.Id))
        .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
                     dataBinding.Ajax()
                       .OperationMode(GridOperationMode.Client)
                       .Select("AjaxGetAll", "ProcurementActions")
                       .Update("AjaxUpdate", "ProcurementActions")
                       .Delete("AjaxDelete", "ProcurementActions")
                       .Enabled(true)
        )
        .Editable(editing => 
            editing.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
                   .TemplateName("EditProcurementAction")
            )
        .Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(15))
        .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height(500))
        .Filterable()
        .Sortable()
%>
```

I have an ASCX template for the Popup Editor.
[image]

Before I populate the Grid, I have to scan each row for each required field and embed a message for every data point that needs attention.  I do this in the controller as there are several conditional logics to be taken into account.  Once I have a List<string> of messages I iterate the List<string> and produce a simple 4 column HTML table and save that as a string on the row as part of my ViewModel.  (Model.RowList[x].UpdateMessage)  The HTML string looks like this:

```
Model.UpdateMessage = "
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='4'>The following fields require additional data:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Award Amount</td>
        <td>Comments</td>
        <td>Contract Number</td>
        <td>Number of Option Years</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Planned CA Responsible</td>
        <td>Actual CA Responsible</td>
        <td>Cost Price Analysis Date</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>";
```

My Popup Template basically starts off with:

```
<fieldset style="width: 1085px">
    <legend>Procurement Action</legend>
    <%= Html.HiddenFor(c => c.Id) %>    <=== WORKS ===
    <%= MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.UpdateMessage) %>    <=== DOES NOT WORK ===
    <%= Model.UpdateMessage.ToMvcHtmlString() %>    <=== DOES NOT WORK ===
    <%= Model.UpdateMessage %>    <=== DOES NOT WORK ===
    <%= Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.UpdateMessage) %>    <=== WORKS ===
```

- Obviously, displaying HTML in a TextAreaFor box is ugly and not at all what I need/want.
- Any version of trying to convert the string to MvcHtmlString does not render the table!  <Grrrrr!/>
- This really should be simple!

Any ideas???

TIA

-kb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the Telerik grid only loads and renders the popup editor template one time, with an empty/default model. For each subsequent popup "edit" command, the grid appears to do its own binding (client side) to *only the form fields* in the editor template, which explains why your TextArea and hidden fields work, but including inline HTML does not.

I believe the only way around this is to declare a Telerik client (JavaScript) event for OnEdit and dynamically populate the contents of a DIV or other container using that JavaScript event handler.

**On your grid declaration in your view:**

```
.ClientEvents(e => e.OnEdit("ProcurementActionGrid_onEdit")
```

**In a `<script>` block or included .js file from your view:**

```
function ProcurementActionGrid_onEdit(e) {
    var targetDiv = $(e.form).find('.injectUpdateMsgHtmlHere');
    targetDiv.html(e.dataItem.UpdateMessage);
}
```

*(Note: the above is shown using jQuery shortcuts, but could be done without jQuery if desired)*

**And finally, in your .ascx EditorTemplate:**

```
<div class="injectUpdateMsgHtmlHere"></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly how I ended up doing it in the end.  Thanks for the clear answer and for matching what I ended up coding last week.